# Expected first-returning time of Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

My question is as follows:

Consider a time-homogeneous Markov chain X = ($X_0$ , $X_1$ , . . .) with values in {1, 2, 3} and one-step transition probabilities given by the following matrix:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1/4 & 1/2 & 1/4 \\
    1/3 & 0 & 2/3 \\
    1/2 & 0 & 1/3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Assume $X_0$ = 1. Let $T_{i1}$ =min{n≥1:$X_n$ =1} be the first time the chain returns to 1 if it starts from state i, i ∈ {1, 2, 3}. By using first step decomposition or by any other means, find the quantity

$μ_{11}$ :=E[$T_{11}$|$X_0$ =1] i.e the expected first time that the chain returns to 1, having started at 1.

My definition of first step decomposition is $f_{ij}^*$ = $p_{ij}$ + $\sum$$_{l\ne j}$$p_{il}$$f_{lj}^*$ where $f_{ij}^*$ = P($T_{ij}$ < $\infty$| $X_0$ = i). Recursively I seem to have found that $f_{11}^*$=$f_{21}^*$=$f_{31}^*$=1 which makes sense though I am not sure if this is even useful. I thought I could use these probabilities in the usual definition for expectation as for some discrete random variable but again I am not sure.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've found is the *probability* that we'll return to the first state, and it's good that that probability is $1$ for every state (we'd be in trouble if it weren't) but not what we're looking for.

There's a similar first-step decomposition for hitting times. If $\mu_{ij}$ is the expected number of steps it takes to go from state $i$ to state $j$, then
$$
   \mu_{ij} = 1 + \sum_{k \ne j} p_{ik} \mu_{kj}
$$
The idea is that we take a step from $i$; if we end up in state $j$ we're done, and if we end up in state $k \ne j$, then we need $\mu_{kj}$ more steps on average, and we add $1$ to account for the step we've just taken.

Comment: Thank you so much! Recursively I have found the answer to be 8/3 which aligns with my peers. Thank you again.